# Understand new fast computation algorithm elliptic point

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm reading about new fast computation algorithm elliptic point in this paper [Analyzing the Point Multiplication Operation of
Elliptic Curve Cryptosystem over Prime Field for
Parallel Processing](http://ccis2k.org/iajit/PDF/vol.11,no.4/5008.pdf). But I don't understand algorithm at page 324:
[image]

First it creates new SUM(0,0) and Return SUM = SUM(0,0) + P. I'm so confusing at this moment when I read to this part.

```
Algorithm 3: PointDoublingBinary(Point P)
// Point Doubling Operations of Binary of kP
Input :Point P, Quotient Q.
Output: QP is summation of P
1. Point Sum (0, 0);
2. Sum = QP
a. If (P (x, y) == Sum(0, 0)) then
    Sum (x, y) = P (x, y);
b. Else if (P (x, y) == Sum (x, -y)) then
    Sum (x, y) = P (x, 0);
c. Else if (P (x, y) == Sum (x, y)) then
    Sum (x, y) = P (x, y) + Sum (x, y);
d. Else // (P (x, y)! = Sum (x, y))
    Sum (x, y) = P (x, y) + Sum (x, y);
e. End if
3. Return Sum
```

And double skew look like the same at `DoubleBinary` function

```
Algorithm 4: PointDoublingSkew(Point P)
// Point Doubling Operations of Skew of kP
Input: Point P, Reminder R
Output: RP is summation of P
1. Point Sum = (0, 0);
2. If (P (x, y) == Sum (0, 0)) then
   Sum (x, y); = P (x, y);
3. Else if (P (x, y) == Sum (x, -y)) then
   Sum (x, y) = P (x, 0);
4. Else if (P (x, y) == Sum (x, y)) then
   Sum (x, y) = P (x, y) + Sum (x, y);
5. Else // (P (x, y)! = Sum (x, y))
   Sum (x, y) = P (x, y) + Sum (x, y);
6. End if
7. Return SUM
```

Last return P1 + P2, but I think return P was enough for this function. When I run a test for this algorithm with number and recursive:

```
def new_algro(P, k):
    R0 = R1 = 0
    P1 = P
    if k == 1:
        R0 = P

    if k > 1:
           q = k/2
           if q > 0:
               R0 = new_algro(P, q)
               P = R0 + R0
           if k % 2:
               R1 = P + P1
               P = R1
return P
```

It work well but not fast as `Double and add` or `Montgo Ladder` and not working with big number.
Please help me understand this algorithm.

Comment: At first glance, this is just the standard binary point multiplication algorithm.  I'm not sure if there's anything here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that this algorithm is really worth a lot of study; the authors are obviously new to the field, and managed to reinvent a well-known method (and used rather hard to follow terminology to describe it).

The base algorithm is essentially the same as exp_by_squaring_iterative from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) (except the algorithm on the page uses multiplicative notation, not additive; essentially, replace every '*' on the page with a '+', and you're there).

Yes, it appears that the algorithm they have listed does a redundant add at the end (and hence gives the wrong answer); that should be easy to fix, but you're still left with an algorithm that's not as good.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand this algorithm and your advice!